# How to access object property in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, object, mongoose

This is my schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  total: {
    avg_time: Number,
    avg_guesses: Number,
    guessed: Number
  }
});
```

I want to create a collection and to set properties avg_time, avg_guesses and avg_guessed to 0.
I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
var user_data = new userSchema({username: usernames[i], total.avg_time: 0, total: avg_guesses: 0, total: guessed: 0});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is creating a new Schema called user_data, instead of creating a document in mongodb.
You have to compile your schema into a model and then create documents. For example,

```
var user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

var user_data = new user({
                      username:'foo',
                      total:{
                            avg_time: 0,
                            avg_guesses: 0,
                            guessed: 0
                      }
                 });
```

I recommend looking at the documentation for mongoose. Click [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html).